# Need some clarification about having return and print statements in the same function for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, printing, return

So I am practicing for my exam by reviewing older exams. And I got tripped up by a question as it pertains to print and return functions. Need some clarification on this.

In the question, I am given the following code:

```
def square(x):
""" (number) -> number
"""
print('LINE A:', x)
x = x * x
print('LINE B:', x)
return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 5
    print('LINE C:', x)
    square(x)
    print('LINE D:', x)
    square(x + 1)
    print('LINE E:', x)
```

I am asked to write what the program will print per line. For my answer I wrote:

```
LINE C: 5
LINE A: 5
LINE B: 25
25
LINE D: 5
LINE A: 6
LINE B: 36
36
LINE E: 5
```

However, as I looked over the solution provided, I got one thing wrong. Here is what the actual solution is for the question.

```
LINE C: 5
LINE A: 5
LINE B: 25
LINE D: 5
LINE A: 6
LINE B: 36
LINE E: 5
```

It's almost the same, but for some reason, 25 and 36 by themselves are not printed. This perplexes me. Does it have something to do with there being multiple print statements?

I fiddled around with some code in the shell to try and understand this.

I do this:

```
>>> def test(num):
    final = num * 2
    print(num)
    return final

>>> test(2)
2
4
```

And it makes sense, my print statement and return statement both function properly as they should be.

I do another test, but with two print statements like in the question, and I still get the results as intended.

```
>>> def test(num):
    final = num * 2
    print("result is:", final)
    print('Poop is', final)
    return num

>>> test(2)
result is: 4
Poop is 4
2
```

So why is it that the functions in the practice exam question don't return 25 and 36?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` by itself does not print anything. In order for your original output to be correct, the code would have to be changed to `print(square(x))` and `print(square(x+1))`

Answer (score 0):

The function `square` does return 25 and 36, however, nothing prints them out.

Edit: I should also note that while you're in the interactive console, the result of the last expression will also be sent to output, this isn't the case when just running python code from the interpreter.